# The task of mathematical logic (theorem on unambiguity of expression analysis)

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Suppose that in some signature among the functional symbols there are symbols of logical operations. within the terms used Polish notation, but in all the formula - standard infix. Will the theorem on the uniqueness of the analysis be fulfilled (theorem on unambiguity of expression analysis)?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're talking about; do you mean expressions like "$\forall x(fgx=hx\vee \neg fx=gx)$" ($f,g,h$ function symbols)?

Comment: Yes, but in terms - Poland notations. For example, ∀x( A(∨ ^ a b ¬c)   ∨    B(¬ ∨ a b)).

Comment: Hello Mike, thanks for your question. I might be not able to answer your question, but in any case it may be of help to provide some more information and give maybe some background where you define your issues more mathematically or give links where this is done. Specifically concerning the theorem you care about. Cheers, Ettore